What is the chances of me getting into top 20 university in US with low gpa? (ranking from US News)
Background
I'm a year 1 undergrad at The University of Hong Kong under the faculty of Engineering. My CGPA is 3.0-3.3/4.3 and converted to 3.5x - 3.6x/4.0 with WES GPA Convertor (free version, I did not pay 200USD). I plan to do my research throughout year 2 - 3, and apply for a PhD at the start of year 4.
I will also try to increase my CGPA.
Thoughts
I would like to apply for top 20 university in US such as Columbia University in the City of New York. Given my background, what is the chance of me getting in?
Thanks in advance!
